# Script to change strings from lookup table?

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I'm not a programmer and I have no idea what I'm doing, so this has probably been answered on here lots of times but I don't know the terms to find the answer (or what to do next if i find an answer)...

I have a text file with a bunch of strings in it that i want to replace, and an excel file where one column is the strings to replace, and one column is the replacements.

Strings to be replaced look like this (but the naming isn't consistent so it can't just be a cutting-down, having a lookup table is necessary):

```
gi|5566332|gb|AF164131.1| Uroleptus pisces macronuclear small-subunit ribosomal RNA gene, complete sequence
```

Strings to replace them with look like this:

```
AF164131
```

(1) How should I format the lookup table - something like a tab delimited file?

(2) How do I write a script to do the replacements?

This should probably just be some easy BASH or sed script, but I haven't really got the hang of how to write them...

Comment: This is a very open question which is difficult to answer. You are more likely to get an answer at StackOverflow if you phrase your question more specific and also include your attempts at the solution. One thought comes to my mind directly: Microsoft Excel and Unix bash/sed do not go well with each other. The easiest thing to do is proabably is to quickly leave the "Windows domain" by exporting the Excel data in some kind of CSV file so that it will be available to you at Unix level. Or you could save the Excel file in XML format and use XSLT to generate the script doing the replacement.

Comment: I completely agree re MSExcel. It's just my intermediate between horrendously GUIfied stuff for dealing with sequence data, and trying to deal with text files.  So, I export the table as .csv or .tsv ... but then what? i guess i could just create a huge series of grep and sed commands in the actual excel table and then paste them all into my terminal. But that is probably stupid for some reason I haven't thought of yet...

Comment: OK - my attempt to solve this is very inelegant. it is creating columns in an excel file: "sed 's/oldname/newname/g' filename n > filename n+1" and then pasting the commands all into my terminal

Comment: Just saw your comment. So your approach is not very different from mine, just that I moved the `sed` command creating to the shell level and and combined all of them in a single control file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk '{sub(/AF164131/,"new txt")}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Export your excel spreadsheet as tab-delimited text to a file name "map.txt" and then do this:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { map[$1] = $2; next }
$0 in map { $0 = map[$0] }
{ print }
' map.txt textfile
```

assuming textfile contains the strings you want to replace. If that doesn't work for you, update your questions with a few lines of representative input and expected output as right now your textfile format isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that my answer was unsafe with respect to the interpretation of the regular expressions. I retreated it so that no damage will be done.